# MVP4G and IE7 compatibility issues?

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-7, mvp4g

Is there anyone having issues with GWT, MVP4G and IE7? For some reason i'm having an issue only with that browser where the two presenters (and views) do not get kicked off. Essentially, I have the rootView and presenter with one eventbus. I have then added two views within some flowpanels. I do get my rootView but I do not get the content which is supposed to be the other two views.

This works perfectly fine in IE8 and all other browsers but IE7 (or IE6 but don't care about IE6). Is it possible i'm doing something wrong? Or a particular process that needs to be followed in order for IE7 to work.

Comment: Which version of GWT? http://www.techspot.com/news/44076-google-to-drop-support-for-ie7-firefox-35-safari-3.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to drop the Support for IE7. It should be down to less than 4% of desktop usage. But it also may be a pure CSS-bug. Are the elements in the DOM?

Maybe you can install the developer tools to the IE7.

**edit:**
I think one should know, where the webapplication will be used:
http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/08/will-the-real-browser-stats-please-stand-up/